# How to allow scripts to access Personal Access Token from yaml builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This is my azure-pipelines.yaml:

```
parameters:
- name: token
  type: string

...
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'PowerShell Script
      inputs:
        targetType: filePath
        filePath: ./Scripts/CreatePRBuildTask.ps1
        arguments: '-token ${{ parameters.token }}'
```

I see no value for $token variable while passing the value as above. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample of how to pass variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

> You can also use secret variables outside of scripts. For example, you
> can map secret variables to tasks using the variables definition. This
> example shows how to use secret variables $(vmsUser) and
> $(vmsAdminPass) in an Azure file copy task.

```
variables:
  VMS_USER: $(vmsUser)
  VMS_PASS: $(vmsAdminPass)

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    SourcePath: 'my/path'
    azureSubscription: 'my-subscription'
    Destination: 'AzureVMs'
    storage: 'my-storage'
    resourceGroup: 'my-rg'
    vmsAdminUserName: $(VMS_USER)
    vmsAdminPassword: $(VMS_PASS)
```